# @Transactional not working with spring and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions, annotations

I am trying to do spring transactions with `@Transactional` without any success.

Excerpt from my applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="hibex" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" p:url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibex"
    p:username="clubspace" p:password="clubspace" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="beanValidationEventListener" />
</bean>

<!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <!--  org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

My full spring config file is [here](http://pastebin.com/Bmbp4GyQ).

And my method, where transactions does not work:

```
@Transactional
public void m2() {
    OwnerBO owner2 = ownerManager.get(owner.getId());
    owner2.getPets().add(new PetBO("Ubul"));
}
```

This causes:

```
1375 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: hibex.bo.OwnerBO.pets, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: hibex.bo.OwnerBO.pets, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:212)
    at hibex.code.Service.m2(Service.java:52)
    at hibex.code.App.run(App.java:15)
    at hibex.code.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: hibex.bo.OwnerBO.pets, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:212)
    at hibex.code.Service.m2(Service.java:52)
    at hibex.code.App.run(App.java:15)
    at hibex.code.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

The service is called from this class:

```
@Component
public class App {
    @Autowired
    private Service service;
    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    public void run() {
        service.m2();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

GenericManager is here: [GenericManager on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fuNpSGqJ)

the get method:

```
public T get(PK id) {
    return dao.findById(id);
}
```

And the `GenericDaoImpl#findById(PK)`

```
public E findById(PK id) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().get(getEntityClass(), id);
}
```

Thanks

Changelog: Just added additional infos (necessary code snippets)

Comment: Can you show me the code of OwnerManager.get()  (I suspect that this is in your generic template). Problem is not so much with transactions but with the fact that the Hibernate Session gets closed when you don't want it to

Comment: I modify the post to expose get()

Answer (score 2):

`HibernateTransactionManager` should be supplied with `SessionFactory`, see [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html).

Comment: So do you say, that I should have `<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />` in my `transactionManager` bean?

Comment: Ah thanks, that helped me (upvote), but not the _final_ solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

The exception is related to Hibernate lazy loading support. 
It appears that Hibernate session is not open when you are calling owner2.getPets().add(). 
Could it be that ownerManager.get() is closing the Session ?

Comment: I modified the post to include the `get()` method

Comment: "Lazy loading will also just work with an open Hibernate Session, either within a transaction or within OpenSessionInViewFilter/Interceptor. "

see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html

Comment: You might want to annotate OwnerManager#get method with @Transactional if it isn't already annotated as such.